# Sytem will not hibernate (swap>memory) Help Please! :(

Tags: 14.04, hibernate

I am unable to hibernate my system with `sudo pm-hibernate`. The screen only flashes then it returns to desktop, nothing happens.

Results to `free`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8072760    2907808    5164952     277220     140412    1074456
-/+ buffers/cache:    1692940    6379820
Swap:      9437180          0    9437180
```

Results for `dmesg | tail`:

```
[10113.776950] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=69.80.53.244 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33815 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57561 DPT=27885 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10113.777301] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=69.80.53.244 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33816 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57561 DPT=27885 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10113.805205] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=24.55.224.184 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=112 ID=26992 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37970 DPT=40871 WINDOW=258 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10113.897292] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=69.80.53.244 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=13714 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27885 DPT=57561 WINDOW=17280 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10113.935766] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=69.80.53.244 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33817 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57561 DPT=27885 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10113.968999] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=209.116.151.66 LEN=89 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40424 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40901 DPT=443 WINDOW=341 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10113.978935] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=190.80.137.167 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=10584 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=7224 DPT=51487 WINDOW=67 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10114.073656] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=69.80.53.244 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=118 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=13717 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27885 DPT=57561 WINDOW=17272 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.073678] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=69.80.53.244 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33818 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57561 DPT=27885 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10114.073805] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3508 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44386 DPT=44386 LEN=9 
[10114.073813] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3508 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44386 DPT=44386 LEN=9 
[10114.073823] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3509 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44386 DPT=44386 LEN=9 
[10114.073827] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3509 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44386 DPT=44386 LEN=9 
[10114.073885] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=69.80.53.244 LEN=101 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33819 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57561 DPT=27885 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.073897] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3510 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44386 DPT=44386 LEN=9 
[10114.073902] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3510 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44386 DPT=44386 LEN=9 
[10114.073977] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3511 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44386 DPT=44386 LEN=9 
[10114.073982] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=29 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3511 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44386 DPT=44386 LEN=9 
[10114.288686] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=209.116.151.66 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=89 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=44887 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=40901 WINDOW=558 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.288709] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=209.116.151.66 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40901 DPT=443 WINDOW=341 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10114.374596] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=69.80.53.244 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=13723 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27885 DPT=57561 WINDOW=17223 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10114.374611] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=69.80.53.244 LEN=65 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33820 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57561 DPT=27885 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.493403] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=69.80.53.244 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=13724 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27885 DPT=57561 WINDOW=17210 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.493741] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=249 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19276 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.531554] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=69.80.53.244 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33821 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57561 DPT=27885 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10114.698159] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10847 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10114.760388] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=514 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35714 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40305 DPT=7337 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.760401] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=514 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35714 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40305 DPT=7337 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.761131] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=380 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3642 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44253 DPT=44253 LEN=360 
[10114.761141] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=380 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3642 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44253 DPT=44253 LEN=360 
[10114.761159] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=410 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=31981 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=7337 DPT=40305 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.761167] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=410 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=31981 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=7337 DPT=40305 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.761180] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35715 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40305 DPT=7337 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10114.761188] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35715 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40305 DPT=7337 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10114.902879] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10848 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10114.902898] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19277 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10115.107610] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=62 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10849 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10115.107622] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19278 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10117.762736] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=514 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35716 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40305 DPT=7337 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10117.762750] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=514 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35716 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40305 DPT=7337 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10117.763443] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=380 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3812 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44253 DPT=44253 LEN=360 
[10117.763453] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=380 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3812 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44253 DPT=44253 LEN=360 
[10117.763469] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=410 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=31982 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=7337 DPT=40305 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10117.763477] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=410 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=31982 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=7337 DPT=40305 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10117.763488] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35717 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40305 DPT=7337 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10117.763493] [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35717 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40305 DPT=7337 WINDOW=6146 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.163869] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=1076 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19279 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10118.163908] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=1500 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19280 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.163918] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=1500 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19281 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.166009] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=576 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=26212 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=4 [SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=1500 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=19280 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 ] MTU=1492 
[10118.166025] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=1492 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19282 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.166038] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19283 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.166042] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=1492 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19284 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.166047] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19285 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.166737] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=576 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=26213 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=4 [SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=1500 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=19281 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 ] MTU=1492 
[10118.383305] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10850 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.383320] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=999 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19286 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10118.383444] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10851 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.383907] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10852 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.384069] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10853 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.384209] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10854 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.588043] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10118.588236] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=a0:a8:cd:99:5d:a9:e0:cb:4e:ff:35:a3:08:00 SRC=65.55.223.27 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=10856 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40034 DPT=47823 WINDOW=83 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
[10118.588244] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=192.168.1.5 DST=65.55.223.27 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19287 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47823 DPT=40034 WINDOW=1444 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[10524.049356] systemd-hostnamed[20747]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[11024.093441] TuxOnIce 3.3, with support for usm, compression, block i/o, swap storage, file storage, userui.
[11024.093491] Scanning swap devices for TuxOnIce signature...
[11024.112630] TuxOnIce scan: No image found.
[11024.112634] Scanning swap devices for TuxOnIce signature...
[11024.130714] TuxOnIce scan: No image found.
[11024.130726] TuxOnIce: Can't translate "" into a device id yet.
[11024.130727] TuxOnIce: No matching enabled allocator found. Resuming disabled.
```

I assume this is the information would help...

My swap is obviously bigger than my memory so I am completely puzzled, please can someone help me with problem :(

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @user300665 by any chance can you assist me with this problem?

Comment: Run 'dmesg | tail' right after hibernation fails. Should have some juicy details in there about what happened.

Comment: @aroll605 I updated the question with the `dmesg | tail` results.

Comment: That's your firewall polluting the log a bit. Try running 'dmesg' without 'tail' and paste the last 100 lines or so.

Comment: @aroll605 without the tail it is even worst!!! endless lines on the same thing

Comment: @aroll605 ok i turnt off the firewall and i saw this at the end or `dmesg` I updated the question.

Comment: This is the kernel resuming from hibernation, it seems. Look a bit above those. Do 'dmesg', let it finish outputting everything, and paste the last 50-100 lines.

Comment: @aroll605 I did but i'm only seeing the firewall audits... :(

Comment: Look at `/var/log/pm-powersave.log` and `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`. Also, you could eliminate the UFW AUDIT lines like with `dmesg -T | egrep -v "UFW AUDIT" >dmesg.cleaned`